# Dynamic Query grouping specific fields

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm trying to display a table in front-end. The applications is written in AngularJS and PHP with MySQL.

My table is something like:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| id_person | id_car | value  |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| 1         |   1    |   1000 |
| 1         |   2    |   2000 |
| 2         |   1    |   2200 |
| 2         |   2    |   1100 |
| 3         |   3    |   3000 |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

I need to show a table in front-end in this format:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+---------+
|           | Car 1  | Car 2  |  Car 3  |
+-----------+--------+--------+---------|
| Person 1  |  1000  |   2000 |    0    |
| Person 2  |  2200  |   1100 |    0    |
| Person 3  |   0    |   0    |  3000   |
+-----------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Each person's value will appear in car's field.
If value is null or doesn't exist, it will show 0 or as a null value.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUM in combination with GROUP BY to pivot the table like you want.

**Create table/insert**

```
CREATE TABLE cars
    (`id_person` INT, `id_car` INT, `value` INT)
;

INSERT INTO cars
    (`id_person`, `id_car`, `value`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1000),
    (1, 2, 2000),
    (2, 1, 2200),
    (2, 2, 1100),
    (3, 3, 3000)
;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT('Person ', cars.id_person) "Person"
 , SUM(CASE WHEN cars.id_car = 1 THEN cars.value ELSE 0 END) "Car 1"
 , SUM(CASE WHEN cars.id_car = 2 THEN cars.value ELSE 0 END) "Car 2"
 , SUM(CASE WHEN cars.id_car = 3 THEN cars.value ELSE 0 END) "Car 3"
FROM
 cars
GROUP BY
 cars.id_person 
ORDER BY
 cars.id_person ASC
```

**Result**

```
Person    Car 1   Car 2   Car 3   
--------  ------  ------  --------
Person 1  1000    2000    0       
Person 2  2200    1100    0       
Person 3  0       0       3000
```

See demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65bf69/1

Or for NULLS

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT('Person ', cars.id_person) "Person"
 , SUM(CASE WHEN cars.id_car = 1 THEN cars.value ELSE NULL END) "Car 1"
 , SUM(CASE WHEN cars.id_car = 2 THEN cars.value ELSE NULL END) "Car 2"
 , SUM(CASE WHEN cars.id_car = 3 THEN cars.value ELSE NULL END) "Car 3"
FROM
 cars
GROUP BY
 cars.id_person 
ORDER BY
 cars.id_person ASC
```

**Result**

```
Person    Car 1   Car 2   Car 3   
--------  ------  ------  --------
Person 1  1000    2000    (NULL)  
Person 2  2200    1100    (NULL)  
Person 3  (NULL)  (NULL)  3000
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65bf69/2

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Return a JSON from your server like

```
[
{
  "person": {"id":1, "name":"Sam"},
  "cars": [
    {"id":1, "name":"Ford", "value": 1000},
    {"id":1, "name":"Audi", "value": 1200}
  ]
},
//....

]
```

Comment: Good, but my problem was exactly that. A query to build the table structure.